# Starting work on a new feature branch before previous branch merged to master

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a small project with one other developer and we have a pretty simple workflow - feature branches branched directly from master.

I've just completed some work on a feature branch A  and created a pull request on GitHub to merge this back into master. The other developer won't be able to review this for a couple of days.

However, I'd like to start work immediately on a new branch B and I would like this branch to include the work I've just done on  branch A. What's the best approach here - should I create branch B from branch A, or should I do something else with merging or rebasing?

Comment: Just create branch B from branch A, and rebase on `master` as things get merged there.

Comment: @alextercete Agree this is a duplicate, I'll go with your answer to the other question

Comment: Please upvote if you found the answer useful. ;)